# Algorithm to find out on which position ZX is?

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, problem-solving

I am having the following problem. Lets consider the alphabet. From `A-Z` there are 26 letters. If its for example `AA`, then its the 27 letter this goes on until for example AWZ which is the `1300` letter in this alphabet. One can visualize an excel spreadsheet for this alphabet(the columns). Lets consider we want to know the position of the the letter(column in excel) `XX` or `BD`. Is there any algorithm to `calculate` this without counting it?

I appreciate your answer!

PS.: Problem is not out of any book. Just asked the question myself, after I used excel ;P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\boxed{\text{Val}(\alpha \beta) = 26\times\text{Val}(\alpha) + \text{Val}(\beta)}$

> *Examples*
>
> $\text{Val}(AA) = 26 \times \text{Val}(A) + \text{Val}(A) = 26 \times 1 + 1 = 27\\ 
> \text{Val}(BD) = 26 \times \text{Val}(B) + \text{Val}(D) = 26 \times 2 + 4 = 56\\
> \text{Val}(XX) = 26 \times \text{Val}(X) + \text{Val}(X) = 26 \times 24 + 24 = 648$

More generally:
$\boxed{\text{Val}(\alpha_n \alpha_{n-1} \ldots \alpha_0) = 26^{n-1} \times \text{Val}(\alpha_n) + 26^{n - 2} \times \text{Val}(\alpha_{n-1}) + \cdots + \text{Val}(\alpha_0)}$

> *Example*
>
> $\text{Val}(AAAAA) = 26^4\times 1 + 26^3 \times 1 + 26^2 \times 1 + 26 \times 1 + 1 = 475255\\
> \text{Val}(KARE) = 26^3 \times 11 + 26^2 \times 1 + 26 \times 18 + 5 = 194485$

Comment: Please give an example! Would this also work with like `AAAAA`?

Comment: @Kare Done. Please check the numbers, though.

Comment: @Kare You can also check this in Excel. Enter $1$ in the first cell ($A$) and $2$ in the second ($B$). Select these two. Then drag the right-bottom corner of the selection-rectangle until you reach the column you want ($XX$, for example).

Comment: @Kare This is just a place value system like the familiar decimal and binary systems. For example $(101)_2 = (1 \times 2^2 + 0 \times 2 + 1)_{10} = (5)_{10}$. And $(423)_{10} = (4 \times 10^2 + 2 \times 10 + 3)_{10} = (423)_{10}$ (no kidding!)